# Hive Insert overwrite table partition is successful, but table stays empty

Tags: hive

I'm trying to insert overwrite an external hive table into a partitioned internal table, using the code below. The code runs 'successfully', but then when I run 'select * from videotracking_playevent limit 10', it never returns any results.

The external table was generated from a directory of recursive folders containing Parquet files, and can be queried. I've tested the regular expressions in this sample, which work fine as well. The Hive log doesn't show any errors.
I have a feeling having partitions is what's messing it up somehow. I don't see why though, any ideas?

```
set hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories=true;
set hive.input.dir.recursive=true;
set hive.supports.subdirectories=true; 
set mapred.input.dir.recursive=true;
set hive.execution.engine=spark;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

INSERT overwrite TABLE videotracking_playevent PARTITION (source, createyear, createmonth, createday)
SELECT
  id_gigya,
  created,
  uid,
  category,
  action,
  video_id,
  program,
  device,
  url,
  video_cms,
  duration,
  position,
  version,
  slot_type,
  slot_position,
  ad_position,
  ad_duration,
  player_type,
  is_embed,
  ad_max_ads,
  ad_max_duration,
  brand,
  casting,
  ip,
  platform,
  subprofile_id,
  channel,
  episode_id,
regexp_replace(regexp_extract(INPUT__FILE__NAME, 'source=[a-z]*', 0),'source=','') AS source,
regexp_replace(regexp_extract(INPUT__FILE__NAME, 'createyear=[0-9]*', 0),'createyear=','') AS createyear,
regexp_replace(regexp_extract(INPUT__FILE__NAME, 'createmonth=[0-9]*', 0),'createmonth=','') AS createmonth,
regexp_replace(regexp_extract(INPUT__FILE__NAME, 'createday=[0-9]*', 0),'createday=','') AS createday
FROM
videotracking_playevent_ext;
```

Comment: Debugging tip -- if you run that query in the fat  `hive` command-line interface, you should see the # of records manipulated at each Map/Reduce step (incl. rows inserted in each target file) somewhere in the logs. Same thing in the thin `beeline` CLI **if** your HS2 configuration enables log fetching *(not a standard JDBC feature, also requires custom coding on client-side if you use custom Java code instead of `beeline`)*

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm getting the same issue here.